# Angular Page Unresponsive error for loading page

Tags: angular

System is giving "Page Unresponsive" error in Angular 7. But we are trying to replicate the same in local couldn't get this error. What will be the cause of this error and how to solve this issue by fixing code changes in Angular. Version is 7

Comment: Do you do any heavy manipulation of the data and sending requests?

Comment: Yes actually multiple API calls and data load from services

Comment: Make sure that there are not any loops with race conditions, that can block the ui like cake. Avoid using calculation heavy expression in template because angular evaluate those expression multiple times in second

Answer (score 0):

Open your application on google chrome and open developer tool (F12)

[image]

Check time of your rest api call
[image]

Also verify console logs

If noting found in all then start performance test and check report
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Im having the same issue now. With the multiple calls, make sure you are disposing of the web api calls once the data has been gotten. This can help a little with this issue. It for sure may be a memory leak issue. For example, with my program, I am getting account details using observables, a subject and using the takeUntil method. With this I can know "when" the objects are returned from the server when the subject is updated with a value. Once this happens, I unsubscribe from the observable as well as the subscription to release the resources. This reduced the time taken to keep the observable open thus reducing how much memory is needed at that moment. However I am still experiencing an unresponsive page on the account page. After checking with the Performance tab in the inspector like vaquar khan mentioned, I noticed the heap resources used is really high at the start of loading these api calls. SO I will try to optimize these further and see what happens.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35844058)